# Eigenvalues of operator squared

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let's consider an operator $A$ acting on a space of infinite dimensions, like $L^2(\mathbf{R})$. It is obvious that any of its eigenvalues $\lambda$ is the square root of an eigenvalue of $A^2$, as $AX = \lambda X \Rightarrow A^2X = \lambda^2 X $. However I am interested in the conditions to reverse the implication, which is showing which eigenvalues of $A^2$ are square of eigenvalues of $A$.
The question is then: what conditions are necessary to have $A^2X = \mu X \Rightarrow AX = \pm \sqrt\mu X $.

I guess if $A$ is diagonalisable, it is sufficient, but I fail to understand what minimal property is necessary. The more I think about it, the more I believe it should be always the case.

Comment: Regarding a counterexample: Consider an orthonormal basis $(e_i)$ of $L^2(\mathbb{R})$ and $Ae_1=e_2$, $Ae_2=e_1$ and $Ae_i=e_i$ for $i\geq 3$. Then $A^2 e_1=e_1$ but $Ae_1\neq \pm e_1$.

Comment: Do you believe the property $\mu \in Sp(A^2) \Rightarrow \pm \sqrt{\mu} \in Sp(A)$ can hold ? Even though your counterexample shows that the associated eigenvectors would not be the same.

Comment: This is a new (good) question, I only can partially answer. It always helps to think of a "finite-dimensional version" of your problem first. In that case, you can think of matrices, for which the answer is yes, since the spectrum contains by definition complex numbers: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/143529 

I don't know if this can be generalized for operators, maybe under certain conditions? (It's obvious when there is a spectral decomposition of $A$).

Comment: Right indeed, it is guaranteed with Schur's decomposition. We would need to extend such a decomposition to the infinite-dimension case.